# Why does ActiveRecord association return two copies of every associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have...

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :elements
end

class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :reports
end
```

I'm seeing some very weird behaviour at the command line:

```
$Element.all
[#<Element id: 1, name: "fdafda", created_at: "2013-03-12 02:10:56", updated_at: "2013-03-12 02:10:56">,
 #<Element id: 2, name: "Foo", created_at: "2013-03-14 10:46:56", updated_at: "2013-03-14 10:46:56">, 
 #<Element id: 3, name: "Bar", created_at: "2013-03-14 10:47:03", updated_at: "2013-03-14 10:47:03">]

$ Report.first.elements
[#<Element id: 2, name: "Foo", created_at: "2013-03-14 10:46:56", updated_at: "2013-03-14 10:46:56">, 
 #<Element id: 2, name: "Foo", created_at: "2013-03-14 10:46:56", updated_at: "2013-03-14 10:46:56">, 
 #<Element id: 3, name: "Bar", created_at: "2013-03-14 10:47:03", updated_at: "2013-03-14 10:47:03">, 
 #<Element id: 3, name: "Bar", created_at: "2013-03-14 10:47:03", updated_at: "2013-03-14 10:47:03">]

(rdb:2) Report.first.elements.uniq
[#<Element id: 2, name: "Foo", created_at: "2013-03-14 10:46:56", updated_at: "2013-03-14 10:46:56">, 
 #<Element id: 3, name: "Bar", created_at: "2013-03-14 10:47:03", updated_at: "2013-03-14 10:47:03">]
```

How is the duplication of elements in `Report.first.elements` even possible? And how can I stop it?

```
rails -v
Rails 3.2.11
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Had a report selector in the form at reports/id/elements/new. If the user selected the current report in the report selector, two links between the element and the report would be created in the join table.